# How to make fixed full page background image on mobile as well as desktop? Wordpress - Divi - CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

So I'm working on a website on Divi for WordPress.

I added CSS code allowing me to set a fixed background image on the homepage, however, on tablet and mobile view the image doesn't cover the whole screen, leaving half of the page white. Is there any way I can set the fixed image to be full-screen on mobile too?

here's the code I got:

---

```
.select_page {
  visibility: hidden;
}

span.mobile_menu_bar:before {
  color: rgba(201,144,0,0.78) !important;
}

.et_mobile_menu {
  border-top: 3px solid rgba(201,144,0,0.78);
}

/* First we have to make the main header transparent */

#main-header {
  background-color: transparent;
}

  #main-header,
  #main-header.et-fixed-header {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

/* Then we turn off the footer */

#main-footer {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

/* Here we make the content of our page builder sections transparent. This is so that the background image shows through */

.et_pb_section {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* Here we set the background image for our specific pages. We also set the background image to cover so that it always fills the screen */
.page-id-15 {
  background-image: url("https://ardakarakaya.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/ARDA1-1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

header#main-header.et-fixed-header, #main-header {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

---

website: ardakarakaya.com

kind regards

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this css need to change:

```
body.custom-background {
...
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```